# WebAPI EnableCors with SupportsCredentials = true not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I have an MVC site deployed to `mysite.mydomain.co` that authenticates against ADFS and creates an auth cookie:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureUserAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
            });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                MetadataAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["adsfs.MetadataAddress"],
                Wtrealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["adsfs.Wtrealm"]
            });
    }
}
```

There is also a WebAPI site deployed on "myapi.mydomain.com" with CORS enabled:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("https://mysite.mydomain.com", "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true });
```

The the user goes to mysite.mydomain.com. The MVC site authenticates against ADFS and I see the auth cookie being set with no problem.

My application is mostly an SPA, so from javascript there's a AJAX calls to `myapi.mydomain.com` using jQuery, setting the `withCredentials` option to `true`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
});
```

That options is supposed to send security credentials (cookies) to the API. At runtime I don't see the cookies being set to the API and I get a 401 (unauthorized) error as expected.

If I run the same code on localhost (except for changing the origins to localhost of course) I see the cookie flowing to the API with no problem. My best guess is it works because it's the same subdomain (localhost) whereas on my servers is "mysite" vs "myapi".

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this issue? I have exactly the same problem!

Comment: Ditto, same problem...